# Disable 'font cache' in VLC on OS X?

Tags: vlc-media-player

Ever since downloading the latest version of VLC with the new interface, VLC irritatingly  generating some kind of font cache. This never used to happen with the previous version of VLC and so presumably isn't related to VLC's ability to play video, so I have two questions.

What is this font cache, and why is the font cache re-generated so often?

More importantly, can I disable the font cache, or the rebuilding of the font cache?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try *Menu » Preferences*, then *Show all* settings. Go to *Video » Subtitles/OSD* and change the *Text rendering module* from "Default" to "Dummy font rendering functions".

[image]

Comment: I tried that, and it hasn't tried rebuilding the font cache again yet, so I'll give it 24 hours to be sure before accepting your answer. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: Doesn't work for me. VLC 2.2.4

Comment: Doesn't work for me. VLC 2.2.6

Comment: Sorry, I don't have a new solution for this, it's from 2012 and I haven't looked into it recently.